# populating binary column based on historic values within group Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, isin

I am working on populating a binary column based on status values a certain product ID traveled through during its lifetime.
Hence, I first sorted my frame by 'id' and 'date'. Now, I would need to code something like:

"If ID currently in status 4 or 6 AND ever been before in status 2 or 3, then frame_ordered['binary'] = 1, else frame_ordered['binary'] = 0"

Accordingly, ID 4556 would be assigned the value 1, and the rest gets 0.
I tried working this out with .isin(), but this is rather simplified version, and doesn't yield the correct result. It lacks the time "traveling part": checking the latest status, and all the values beforehand within a given ID.
Does anyone have a better idea how to solve this? Would be much appreciated.

```
today =  datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
frame = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1245, 4556, 2345, 4556, 1248, 4556, 4556],'status': [1,2,4,5,6, 3, 4], 'date': ['2022-07-01', '2022-03-12', '2022-04-20', '2022-02-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-05-03', '2022-07-01']})
frame_ordered = frame.sort_values(['id','date'], ascending=True)
# mask where the next row has same id as current one
mask = frame_ordered['id'] == frame_ordered['id'].shift(-1)
frame_ordered['binary'] = np.where(mask & frame_ordered['id'].isin([4,6]) & frame_ordered['id'].isin([2, 3]), 1, 0)
frame_ordered
```

Comment: the status in your example decreases sometimes (id 4556: 5 on 2022-02-02 followed by 2 on 2022-03-12) - is this just a typo meaning that status can only increase over time or is this example correct?

Comment: the example is correct: status doesn't follow any numeric order. 6 can be followed by 8, and then it can become 6 again. like: eg. 6,8,6, 3,4,2. It is a memoryless process. Some id's will only have 1 or 2 statuses, some will have gone through 10 status changes with eg. 6 distinct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "ever been before in status 2 or 3" condition can be coded using [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) counting all previous (and the current) occurrences of `2` or `3` in the group.

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1245, 4556, 2345, 4556, 1248, 4556, 4556, 2345],'status': [1,2,4,5,6, 3, 4, 2], 'date': ['2022-07-01', '2022-03-12', '2022-04-20', '2022-02-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-05-03', '2022-07-01', '2022-05-10']})

frame_ordered = frame.sort_values(['id','date'])
frame_ordered['binary'] = frame_ordered.groupby('id').status.transform(lambda x: (x.isin([4, 6]) & x.isin([2,3]).cumsum().gt(0)).astype(int))
```

Result:

```
     id  status        date  binary
0  1245       1  2022-07-01       0
4  1248       6  2022-01-03       0
2  2345       4  2022-04-20       0
7  2345       2  2022-05-10       0
3  4556       5  2022-02-02       0
1  4556       2  2022-03-12       0
5  4556       3  2022-05-03       0
6  4556       4  2022-07-01       1
```

(please note that I added another row for id 2345 where the `4` is followed (instead for preceded) by a `2` and hence should not be marked with a `1`)

Comment: many thanks, this is a very compact and elegant solution. 
But how to achieve that binary gets 1 across all lines for 4556? (not only the last line) 
Also, if instead of "ever been before in status 2 or 3" we needed "the status right before the current one" as condition, would it be .gt(1)?, like: 
frame_ordered['binary'] = frame_ordered.groupby('id').status.transform(lambda x: (x.isin([4, 6]) & x.isin([2,3]).gt(1)).astype(int))

Comment: The first one is easy (set all lines to 1 if the condition is met for the group): `transform(lambda x: ((x.isin([4, 6]) & x.isin([2,3]).cumsum().gt(0)).any()).astype(int))`. The second is more complicated (`.gt(1)` won't work), I guess you need to use `shift` in the lambda. If you need this case I think it's better to ask a new question with carefully designed sample data for this case.

Comment: clear, in case I would post a new question. For now, I am more than happy with the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether the latest entry for `status` for each `id` is in `[4, 6]`.

```
current_state_bool = frame_ordered.drop_duplicates('id', keep='last').set_index('id').status.isin([4, 6])
```

Second, check whether the list of the `status` for each `id` contains an element from `[2, 3]`.

```
group = frame_ordered.groupby('id').status.unique()
previous_state_bool = pd.Series([(2 or 3) in entry for entry in group.values], index=group.index)
```

Then, check whether both conditions are fulfilled.

```
combined_bool = pd.Series(current_state_bool & previous_state_bool, name='binary').astype('int')
```

Finally, merge `frame_ordered` and `combined_bool`.

```
frame_ordered = pd.merge(frame_ordered.drop('binary', axis=1), combined_bool, on='id', how='left')
```

Comment: many thanks, @max_jump, this works correctly and assigns the correct binary values!